# Ciclo for javascript

Tags: javascript, bucles

Hola he intentado hacer lo siguiente pero no entiendo , alguien me podría explicar? porfavor

Crear un vector vacío. Mediante una estructura repetitiva solicitar la carga de elementos por teclado hasta que se ingrese el cero. No almacenar dicho valor en el vector. Luego sumar todas las componentes del vector, mostrar dicha suma y el tamaño del vector.

**1)Aqui está el codigo, pero no entiendo porque hacen repeticiones en indices++ y el for, no bastaria solo con el for**

**2) por ejemplo necesito hacer un array que ya tenga 5 valores en el cual se van ingresando valores a la matriz y siempre he visto que comparan con array.length, entonces si ahora lo comparo con el length del array seria infinito, suponiendo que la variable de comparacion no puede ser distinta de 0, entonces sera siempre menor, que deberia hacer?**

```
var vec=[];
  var valor;
  var indice=0;
  do {
    valor=prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)','');
    valor=parseInt(valor);
    if (valor!=0)
    {
      vec[indice]=valor;
      indice++;
    }
  } while (valor!=0);
  var f;
  var suma=0;
  for(f=0;f<vec.length;f++)
  {
    suma=suma+vec[f];
  }
  document.write('Se ingresaron '+vec.length+' valores<br>');
  document.write('La suma de los valores ingresados es:'+suma);
```

**En mi segundo problema me refiero a hacer esto:**

Tengo un array con 5 valores y quiero ingresarle numeros por teclados y el comun var f = 0 no puede ser distinto de 0 cual seria como el tope para finalizar el for?

Comment: ¿Podrías dividir tus preguntas en puntos? Nos facilitaría responderte a cada uno de ellos.

Comment: ya esta, me cuesta del celular

Comment: Respondido, aunque lo hice antes de la edición. El código no hace lo que dices, es decir, no hace la cuenta sin usar matrices (las usa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respondo a cada punto:

> pero no entiendo porque hacen repeticiones en indices++ y el for, no
>   bastaria solo con el for.

El primer bucle `while` almacena cada elemento introducido en la matriz `vec` en la posición mantenida por la variable `indice`.

En realidad es innecesario tanto el `for` como la matriz `vec`. Con únicamente el bucle `while` podrías dar solución al problema almacenando la suma y el número de elementos en  variables:

```js
var suma = 0, valor = 0, numero = 0;
do {
  valor = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0, ENTER o cualquier otro valor para finalizar)', ''));
  if (isNaN(valor) || valor == 0) {
    break;
  }
  numero++;
  suma += valor;
} while (true);
document.write('<p>Se introdujeron ' + numero + ' valores</p>');
document.write('<p>La suma de los valores ingresados es: ' + suma + '</p>');
```

> y mi segunda duda es si por ejemplo necesito hacer un array que ya
>   tenga 5 valores en el cual se van ingresando valores a la matriz y
>   siempre he visto que comparan con array.length, entonces si ahora lo
>   comparo con el length del array seria infinito, suponiendo que la
>   variable de comparacion no puede ser distinta de 0, entonces sera
>   siempre menor, que deberia hacer?

No te confundas. [`array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/length) no te devuelve realmente el número de elementos que existen actualmente definidos en la matriz (diferentes a `undefined`), si no el número de elementos que habría si estuvieran usados todos los índices numéricos hasta el mayor usado realmente.

También podrías haber usado la variable `indice` si te sientes más cómodo con ella y teniendo en cuenta que ella hace un seguimiento de los elementos que has introducido en la matriz.

Otra forma hubiera sido usar un bucle [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) o [`for each in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for_each...in) aunque no se trate de un objeto. Sólo se seleccionarían los elementos definidos, sin tener que recorrerlos desde el 0 ni pasando por índices `undefined`.

No pasa nada en caso de existir elementos anteriores en la matriz, pero el valor inicial del índice debería comenzar por el siguiente elemento y no por 0:

```js
var vec = [2, 5, 7, 9, 12];
var valor;
var indice = vec.length;
do {
  valor = prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)','');
  valor = parseInt(valor);
  if (!isNaN(valor) && valor != 0)
  {
    vec[indice++] = valor;
  }
} while (valor != 0);
var f;
var suma=0;
for(f=0; f<vec.length; f++)
{
  suma += vec[f];
}
document.write('Se ingresaron '+vec.length+' valores<br>');
document.write('La suma de los valores ingresados es:'+suma);
```

Obviamente si usas [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) no necesitarás conocer el tamaño previo. Yo lo haría (sin encapsularlo en un objeto) así usando [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach):

```js
var vec = [2, 5, 7, 9, 12];
var valor;
do {
  valor = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)', ''));
  if (!isNaN(valor) && valor != 0) {
    vec.push(valor);
  }
} while (valor != 0);
var suma = 0;
vec.forEach(function (numero) {
  suma += numero;
});
document.write('<p>Se introdujeron ' + vec.length + ' valores</p>');
document.write('<p>La suma de los valores ingresados es: ' + suma);
```

Un nuevo ejemplo para lo que me propones con índices fuera de orden:

```js
var vec = [2, 5];
document.write('<p>1.- Aquí la longitud es: ' + vec.length + '</p>');
vec[8] = 1;
document.write('<p>2.- Aquí la longitud es: ' + vec.length + '</p>');
vec[6] = 3;
document.write('<p>3.- Aquí la longitud es: ' + vec.length + '</p>');
var valor;
do {
  valor = parseInt(prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)', ''));
  if (!isNaN(valor) && valor != 0) {
    vec.push(valor);
  }
} while (valor != 0);
var suma = 0, num = 0;
vec.forEach(function (numero, indice) {
  suma += numero;
  num++;
  document.write('1.- Elemento ' + indice + ' = ' + numero + '</p>');
});
document.write('<p>Se introdujeron ' + vec.length + ' valores</p>');
document.write('<p>1.- Se introdujeron REALMENTE ' + num + ' valores</p>');
document.write('<p>1.- La suma de los valores ingresados es: ' + suma + '</p>');
suma = 0; num = 0;
for (var indice in vec) {
  suma += vec[indice];
  num ++;
  document.write('2.- Elemento ' + indice + ' = ' + vec[indice] + '</p>');
}
document.write('<p>1.- Se introdujeron REALMENTE ' + num + ' valores</p>');
document.write('<p>2.- La suma de los valores ingresados es: ' + suma + '</p>');
```

Como puedes ver, en la práctica un bucle `for .. in` ofrece resultados similares a la iteración de `Array.forEach`.

Comment: okey, me quedaron 2 dudas si podrias responderme estaría genial que es: entonces que hace el for y si me podrias dar un ejemplo usando for de mi segunda problema, muchas gracias:)

Comment: Mira mi actualización, en ella te pongo un ejemplo de cómo se trataría el programa si hubiera previamente datos en la matriz `vec`.

Comment: graciaas me han resuelto bastantes dudas y lo otro es: el parametro del foreach recibe el valor de vec[indice++] ?

Comment: No, forEach, como habrás visto en el enlace que te puse, necesita una función que recibirá hasta tres parámetros. Para nuestra tarea con el primero es suficiente. Se llamará a esa función una vez por cada elemento que contenga la matriz.

Comment: mm vale, entonces que recibe? y no se supone que si quiero agregar valores NUEVOS al array porque necesito pasar por todos los otros elementos?

Comment: No es necesario. Si usas `push` los agregas en orden, pero podrías agregar los índices 2, 7 y 8. En ese caso `vec.length` valdría 9, aunque `forEach` se ejecutaría sólo 3 veces.

Comment: Ya tienes un ejemplo con `for .. in`, en el que he aprovechado para mostrarte cómo se comporta la matriz cuando existen previamente elementos en ella. También te he puesto un ejemplo de cómo contar los elementos reales en ambos casos.

Comment: he revisado todo y me va bien es que ni viendo la documentación entiendo de donde sacar los parametros el forEach , osea que cosas reciben los parametros numeros e indice y como lo hace , en que orden? osea como sabe cual parametro ponerlo como numero y cual como indice?

Comment: podrias ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Qué te ocurre?

Comment: con mi anterior comentario

Comment: ¿No te vale con la documentación del [objeto `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) y con lo que he ido explicando en la respuesta?. Repásalo y dime lo que no entiendas.

Answer (score 2):

> No entiendo porque hacen repeticiones en indices++ y el for, no bastaria solo con el for

Ni yo entiendo para qué usas un contador. Es **completamente innecesario**, ya que para agregar un elemento a un array dispones de métodos como [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), el cual agrega un elemento en la posición siguiente al último elemento actua.

```js
var valor = 0;
var vec = [];
do {
  valor = prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)', '');
  valor = parseInt(valor);
  if (valor !== 0) { vec.push(valor); }
} while (valor != 0);
```

Sobre la necesidade del ciclo *for*, es necesario porque lo estás usando para sumar los valores que previamente has almacenado. El bucle *while* lo estás usando para **almacenar valores** dentro del arreglo, mientras que el *for* **para sumar esos valores**.

Sin embargo, no es necesario usar el bucle *for* para sumar los elementos del arreglo. Para esto puedes usar el método [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var valor = 0;
var vec = [];
do {
  valor = prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)', '');
  valor = parseInt(valor);
  if (valor !== 0) { vec.push(valor); }
} while (valor != 0);

var sum = vec.reduce(function(acc, cur) { return acc + cur; });

console.info('Cantidad de elementos:', vec.length);
console.info('Suma de los elementos:', sum);
```

> Por ejemplo necesito hacer un array que ya tenga 5 valores en el cual se van ingresando valores a la matriz y siempre he visto que comparan con array.length, entonces si ahora lo comparo con el length del array seria infinito, suponiendo que la variable de comparacion no puede ser distinta de 0, entonces sera siempre menor, que deberia hacer?

No entiendo a qué te refieres con esto. Tengas los elementos que tengas, **no necesitas tener en cuenta el tamaño actual del arreglo** para agregar nuevos elementos.

Comment: he editado mi post con el segundo problema

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Tu segundo problema se debe a un error de conceptos simplemente. Un array en JavaScript siempre es dinámico, es decir, crecerá mientras tengas disponible memoria, aún cuando creas un array pasando un número al constructor, igual podrás seguir añadiendo elementos. Un array en JavaScript se parece a un List en Java y C# en ese sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí lo tienes de otra manera.:

```
var vec = [];
        var valor;
        var suma = 0;
        do {
            valor = parseInt( prompt('Ingrese un valor entero (0 para finalizar)','') );
            if ( valor != 0 ) {
                vec[ vec.length ] = valor;
                suma+= valor;
            }

        } while ( valor != 0 );

        document.write( 'Se ingresaron ' + vec.length + ' valores<br>' );
        document.write( 'La suma de los valores ingresados es:' + suma );
```